# Query is giving cartesian join

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have below query, it is returning around `65000` rows.

```
 WITH msilk AS (
            SELECT
                k.inventory_item_id        AS inventory_item_id,
                k.organization_id          AS organization_id,
                k.primary_uom_code         AS primary_uom_code,
                k.concatenated_segments    AS concatenated_segments,
                t.description              AS description,
                t.language                 AS language
            FROM
                mtl_system_items_b_kfv  k,
                mtl_system_items_tl     t
            WHERE
                    k.inventory_item_id = t.inventory_item_id
                AND k.organization_id = t.organization_id)
        select * from msilk;
```

If above with clause query i am using twice in existing big query, how can i do the same without using with clause. i did below but it is not working.
any even smallest suggestion would be highly appreciated.

This `with clause query` variable I am using twice. Due to some reason i have to remove with clause and recreate the query. since this variable have been referred twice with different alias I am writing below query and using table twice with different aliases

```
   select count(*) from(  SELECT
            k.inventory_item_id        AS inventory_item_id,
            k.organization_id          AS organization_id,
            k.primary_uom_code         AS primary_uom_code,
            k.concatenated_segments    AS concatenated_segments,
            t.description              AS description,
            t.language                 AS language
        FROM
            mtl_system_items_b_kfv  k,
            mtl_system_items_b_kfv k1,
            mtl_system_items_tl     t,
            mtl_system_items_tl     t1
        WHERE 
               k.inventory_item_id = t.inventory_item_id and
               k1.inventory_item_id = t1.inventory_item_id AND
           k.organization_id = t.organization_id and
            k1.organization_id = t1.organization_id 
            );
```

This should also give 65k record but it is giving around 840k records. is my join condition correct? I need same output as with clause query.

Basically I have to refer both table twice.

Any suggestion is really appreciated.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: thanks Marc. link is very helpful. can you pls help on above please

Comment: Rewrite your query to use explicit joins and do not forget link k with k1 and/or t with t1 :)

Comment: Thanks Arvo. existing join condition are correct? I need to only add 2 more AND clause..right?

Comment: @ShrutiSharma . . . No.  You should have *n - 1* `ON` clauses in a query that is joining *n* tables.  Using commas in the `FROM` clause just leads to the type of problems that you are experiencing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have joined `k` and `t` and you have also joined `k1` and `t1` but you have not joined those two pairs together so they are creating a `CROSS JOIN` and your query is effectively:

```sql
select count(*)
from   (
  SELECT k.inventory_item_id        AS inventory_item_id,
         k.organization_id          AS organization_id,
         k.primary_uom_code         AS primary_uom_code,
         k.concatenated_segments    AS concatenated_segments,
         t.description              AS description,
         t.language                 AS language
  FROM   mtl_system_items_b_kfv  k
         INNER JOIN mtl_system_items_tl t
         ON (   k.inventory_item_id = t.inventory_item_id
            AND k.organization_id   = t.organization_id
            )
         CROSS JOIN mtl_system_items_b_kfv k1
         INNER JOIN mtl_system_items_tl t1
         ON (   k1.inventory_item_id = t1.inventory_item_id
            AND k1.organization_id   = t1.organization_id )
);
```

You need to work out how to correlate between the `k`/`t` pair and the `k1`/`t1` pair and change the `CROSS JOIN` to an `INNER JOIN`. However, there is not enough information in your question for us to tell you how to do that; you will need to work out which columns to correlate on.

Something like:

```sql
select count(*)
from   (
  SELECT k.inventory_item_id        AS inventory_item_id,
         k.organization_id          AS organization_id,
         k.primary_uom_code         AS primary_uom_code,
         k.concatenated_segments    AS concatenated_segments,
         t.description              AS description,
         t.language                 AS language
  FROM   mtl_system_items_b_kfv  k
         INNER JOIN mtl_system_items_tl t
         ON (   k.inventory_item_id = t.inventory_item_id
            AND k.organization_id   = t.organization_id
            )
         INNER JOIN JOIN mtl_system_items_b_kfv k1 -- changed to INNER
         ON (   k.some_column = k1.some_column )   -- added a join condition
         INNER JOIN mtl_system_items_tl t1
         ON (   k1.inventory_item_id = t1.inventory_item_id
            AND k1.organization_id   = t1.organization_id
            AND t.some_other_column  = t1.some_other_column ) -- added a join condition
);
```

> This `with clause query` variable I am using twice. Due to some reason i have to remove with clause and recreate the query.

This seems like an XY-problem when you should be solving the original issue rather than trying to work around the secondary issues created by trying to bypass the first issue. My suggestion would be to work out how to get round this limitation so that you only need to query the table once and can avoid the self join; but, again, you have not provided any details so we can't make any suggestions to help.

Comment: thank you so much. Sadly i can not upvote because I don't have minimum 15 votes required.

Comment: got 15 votes today so upvoted. this answer helped me a lot :)